# How to show just days months and years from DateTime in xamarin collection view?

Tags: c#, datetime, xamarin

I dont want to show hours, minutes and seconds in my collection view from database how can i get rid of them? I have tried format but i cant get how to use it. Here is screenshot [image]
Here is xaml:

```
<DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Margin="0">
                        <Frame x:Name="AnimationFrame" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light='#00d2ff', Dark='#121212'}" Margin="0, 70, 0, 0" HasShadow="False" CornerRadius="30">
                            
                            <StackLayout Padding="20">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Airline}" TextColor ="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="35" FontFamily="Lato" Margin="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                    <ff:CachedImage Source="{Binding ThumbnailUrl}"
                                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"                                                        
                                                    Aspect="AspectFill"
                                                    DownsampleToViewSize="True">
                                        <ff:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="detailTapped_Tapped"/>
                                        </ff:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                                    </ff:CachedImage>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid Margin="0">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="0">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Plane, StringFormat='Plane: {0}'}" FontFamily="Lato" TextColor ="White" FontSize="15"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Airline, StringFormat='Airline: {0}'}" FontFamily="Lato" TextColor ="White" FontSize="15"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Livery, StringFormat='Livery: {0}'}" FontFamily="Lato" TextColor ="White" FontSize="15"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Registration, StringFormat='Reg: {0}'}" FontFamily="Lato" TextColor ="White" FontSize="15"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Airport, StringFormat='Airport: {0}'}" FontFamily="Lato" TextColor ="White" FontSize="15"/>                                                                            
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='Date: {0}'}" FontFamily="Lato" TextColor ="White" FontSize="15"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Comment, StringFormat='Comment: {0}'}" FontFamily="Lato" TextColor ="White" FontSize="15"/>                                            
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <AbsoluteLayout Grid.Column="1">                                                                                       
                                        <Button Text="Delete" TextColor="White" CornerRadius="30" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Lato" BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light='#00aeef', Dark='Black'}" x:Name="deleteButton" Clicked="deleteButton_Clicked" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.8, 1, 100, 50" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"/>
                                    </AbsoluteLayout>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
```

And here is code of Import page:

```
Airplane airplane = new Airplane()
                {
                    Id = (maxPK == null ? 1 : maxPK.Id + 1),
                    SearchId = planeEntry.Text + airlineEntry.Text + liveryEntry.Text + registrationEntry.Text + airportEntry.Text + dateEntry.Text + commentEntry.Text,
                    Plane = planeEntry.Text.ToUpper(),
                    Airline = airlineEntry.Text,
                    Livery = liveryEntry.Text,
                    Registration = registrationEntry.Text.ToUpper(),
                    Airport = airportEntry.Text.ToUpper(),
                    Date = datePicker.Date,
                    Comment = commentEntry.Text,
                    Url = await url,
                    ThumbnailUrl = thumbUrl
                };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [StringFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/string-formatting)

```
Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:MM/dd/yyyy}'}"
```